# OneNote and embedding video content from specific domain

Tags: onenote

I have been looking at the possibility of an add-in for OneNote that would allow for video content to be embedded into OneNote via an iFrame.

From what I can see iFramed content is only permitted from permitted domains (YouTube, DailyMotion etc. [Office Support Article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Insert-online-videos-into-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-0a862f29-665c-43a5-9dd8-68009423cf7c))

Is there any API functionality that can be taken advantage of that would allow for content to be embedded from a different domain?

I have previously attempted using the data-original-src attribute, but as the source is not from one of the listed domains in the above article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to add content to be embedded from a different domain.